# How to unlock the Sqlite database file in EntityFramework.Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have a project that uses `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` `6.0.5` on `net6.0`.  I am expecting the `Sqlite` database file to be unlocked after the `DbContext` has been disposed.

However, the behaviour I am observing is that the `Sqlite` database remains locked after the `DbContext` has been disposed and finalised.  There is a project that reproduces the behaviour [here](https://github.com/seankearon/sqlite-locking).

How can I unlock the database file?

My `DbContext` looks like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    ~MyContext()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finaliser was called.");
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose was called.");
    }

    public static readonly string DbFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "_temp.db");

    public DbSet<Foo> Summaries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Foo>().HasKey(nameof(Foo.Id));
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbFile}");
    }
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
public static void AddItem()
{
    using var ctx = new MyContext();
    ctx.Database.EnsureCreated();
    ctx.Summaries.Add(new Foo {Bar = "Foo"});
    ctx.SaveChanges();        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [SqliteConnection.ClearAllPools()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteconnection.clearallpools) directly or specify no pooling in connection string (`Pooling=false`)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings#pooling